# Duplicated attribute when using both xml.Name and []xml.Attr

Tags: xml, go

When I use a struct like

```
type MyStruct struct {
    XMLName xml.Name
    Attrs []xml.Attrs `xml:",attr,any"`
}
```

The Namespace taken from the `xmlns`-attribute is both an attribute in `Attrs` and the value of `XMLName.Space`. That is unfortunate, because I'd expect, that `Attrs` only contains only attributes, that are not handled elsewhere

Even worse, when I marshal and unmarshal an XML I'd expect to get the same XML. Instead I get something, that looks broken. `xmlns` is doubled

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)


func main() {
    var Foo struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:""`
        Attr []xml.Attr `xml:",attr,any"`
    } = struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:""`
        Attr []xml.Attr `xml:",attr,any"`
    }{}

    str := `
<foo xmlns="bar"/>
    `

    fmt.Println(str)
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &Foo)
    b, _ := xml.Marshal(&Foo)
    fmt.Println(string(b))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ulWy-Paha2

Results in

```
<foo xmlns="bar"/>

<foo xmlns="bar" xmlns="bar"></foo>
```

How can I avoid this? Is there's a way to tell the decoder to simply ignore certain attributes completely?

Comment: In case you want to avoid at least the double `xmlns` after `Marshal` you could change the `XMLName` tag from `xml:""` to `xml:"foo"`. As far as the main issue goes, seems to me that `any` implies the behaviour you see and I don't think there's some other method that uses tags to change that behaviour. You might want to look at the `Unmarshaler` interface, i believe you should be able to utilize that.